# is it true in case of graphs that shortest path change?

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory

In a graph, there is a shortest path between two nodes. Now, If I add a constant value to each of the edge weights of the graph, will this shortest path change?

Comment: If the value is actually constant (IE: plus 100 to each) then no it wont. All you will do is increase the cost by C*P where C is the constant and P is the number of edges in the shortest path. If the cost was variable, the answer would be "probably".

Answer (score 1):

It can change, if the *weighted* shortest path is not the *unweighted* shortest path.  Here is a simple example.

[image: Weighted Graph]

There are two paths between 1 and 3:
1-> 2 -> 3    has weight 2
1-> 3         has weight 3
so the shortest path is 1->2->3.

But if you add 10 to the weight for each path,  the weights become
1-> 2 -> 3    has weight 22
1-> 3         has weight 13
so the shortest path is 1->3.